# Get time of scheduled job from resque_scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque-scheduler

I have my resque_scheduler set run clean up task every 2 min. The clean up task will clean up items in the 2 min interval. This is my yml:

```
scheduled_tasks:
  cleanup:
    class: "BackgroundJobs::Cleanup"
    every: "120s"
    description: "cleans up items in the 2 min interval"
```

Here's the job

```
module BackgroundJobs
  class Cleanup
    @queue = :cleanup

    def self.perform(options = {})
      # do cleanup here
    end
  end
end
```

The job queues fine and is picked up fine. However, in the perform, it needs to know what period it's supposed to cleanup. For exampled, if something is queued at 2:32, I want it to clean up items from 2:30 to 2:32. However, the job might not be picked up until much later, e.g. 2:35. I have no information about when it was queued. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) might help.

Comment: It works. I am going to put my work including code into a blog entry and link to it from here so others can reference it.

Comment: Awesome. That's a really great idea.

Comment: Here's a link to some sample code for reference
http://blog.grantoo.com/2014/03/improve-your-resque-scheduler-with-resque-status/